# get method for linked lists not working... incompatible types

Tags: java, list, get, linked-list

The method is supposed to return a node of type "type" from a link list at a given index.

```
 public type get(int index) throws Exception
    {
    int currPos = 0;
    Node<type> curr = null;

    if(start!= null && index >=0)
    {
        curr = start;
        while(currPos != index && curr != null)
        {
            curr = curr.getNext();
            currPos++;
        }
    }

    return curr;
```

why is it giving me an "incompatible types" error at compile time ?

Comment: what is "start" ? Where is it defined?

Comment: @CristianMeneses - I assume that `start` is a field that references the first node in the list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've declared the method to return a `type` object, but you're trying to return `curr` which is declared as `Node<type>`. Presumably class `Node` has a `getValue()` method (or something equivalent) to retrieve the `type` object stored in the node. You should change the last line to:

```
return curr.getValue();
```

Better yet, since it is possible for `curr` to be `null` at that point:

```
return curr == null ? null : curr.getValue();
```

Comment: @MateiZera - Glad it worked. On re-reading your code, I see that it is possible for `curr` to `null` when the `return` statement is reached. It would be better to change the last line to: `return curr == null ? null : curr.getValue();`.